# Parsleyjs: how to cancel default message display

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, parsley.js

I'm building a form in which I want to display errors using Twitter Bootstrap Popover (like here: https://rentmatic.com/, try to submit with the form empty).

This requires me to configure a `popover()` every time an error is found.

`ParsleyJS` automatically adds errors in a given container which can be customized, but I want to override this by calling my custom function.

I've seen there's a `listener.onFieldError` which could allow me to configure the popover, but does not offer me any way to cancel default Parsley behaviour.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the option 'showErrors:false' or you could set the error messages to 'display:none'.

```
ul.parsley-error-list {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I totally overlook that option. Thanks!